# codeigniter get database field of last 1 minute

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to get the database result of last 1 minutes.. The database  look like this:

```
id| from | to  | username | status | dbtime
-------------------------------------------------------
1 | u_1  | v_2 | myname   | 0      | 2015-02-19 14:30:0
2 | u_1  | v_2 | myname1  | 1      | 2015-02-19 14:30:0
3 | u_3  | v_1 | myname2  | 0      | 2015-02-19 16:30:0
4 | u_1  | v_2 | myname3  | 1      | 2015-02-19 16:30:0
5 | u_1  | v_2 | myname4  | 0      | 2015-02-19 16:30:0
```

Suppose current time is 2015-02-19 16:30:0 .. My target is to get the id number 4 from the database, as its in current time and status is 1 .. here is my query:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->order_by('dbtime', 'asc');
$result = $this->db->get_where('dbname', array('to' => $someid, 'status' => 1, 'dbtime >=' => time()- 90, ),1 );
if ($result->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return 1;
}
else {
  return 0;
}
```

But this query is not giving me the expected result. Its returning me the database column id  2 rather id no 4 ...

Comment: not working.. in this case its not returning anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason to why your code is not working is that you're trying to compare two different date formats. Mysql will need to see equivalent data to whats stored in order to run comparisons. This is what I would do:

```
function getData($someid) {
    $curr = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $last_min = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 minutes'));

    $this->db->select();
    $this->db->from('dbname');
    $this->db->where('to', $someid);
    $this->db->where('status', 1);
    $this->db->where('dbtime >=', $last_min);
    $this->db->where('dbtime <=', $curr);
    $this->db->order_by('dbtime', 'asc');
    $result = $this->db->get();
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: great... just whai I have needed :)

Comment: awesome. glad i was able to help

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->order_by('dbtime', 'asc');
$result = $this->db->get_where('dbname', array('to' => $someid, 'status' => 1, 'dbtime' => date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute)),1 );
if ($result->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return 1;
}
else {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake 
Date condition should like this:
'dbtime' => date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute)

Comment: no luck... not returning anything... atleast it supposed to return 1 or 0

Comment: It will works like this if current time is : 2015-02-19 09:46:00 then date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) will return 2015-02-19 09:45:00.

Comment: I dont know.. seems date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) is not working.. In my codeigniter model if i write this the model query is not executing at all

Comment: $this->db->where("dbtime'= DATE_SUB(NOW(),interval 1 minute)", NULL, FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('tablename');
This will help you finally.